# IR remote ubuntu 17.04

Tags: remote, 17.04

Just upgraded from 16.10. Now my ir remote don't work anymore.
Tried reinstalling LIRC no change.

No config of lirc appears after install or with:
`dpkg-reconfigure lirc`

The irw command shows nothing when pressing my remote.

I'm using Intel NUC NUC5CPYH computer. with buildt in IR sensor.

It has been working flawlessly in Ubuntu 16.10. No go in 17.04.

Anybody knows why and how to fix?
Do I have to go back to 16.10?

Comment: If this is a bug, then please submit a [bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the functionality of lirc has moved into the kernel. Uninstall lirc. Confirm that `ir-keytable` is installed. Then `man ir-keytable` for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have been struggling for hours trying to get my remote to work properly with Kodi. Have gotten some of the buttons to work. But not to good. Usinc protocol RC6 and MCE Keyboard. And programed my Logitech remote as MCE Remote and MCE Keyboard. But not funcioning properly. Are there any good guides to setting up remote with ir-keytable?
I'm really struggling and frustrated that I can't use LIRC. With LIRC it was just to choose media center remote from the list, and it has been working flawlessly for year. Now it's only struggle , and not working properly. :-(

Comment: Use `ir-keytable` and `ir-keytable -t` to get the basics that you need. Then use `ir-keytable -w` to write the file out to the device key table. If you Google `ir-keytable` there are plenty of how-tos available online. Yes, it is a little tricky the first time. I'm still learning it myself. For me, I've got one remote working perfectly. The other remote only partially. LIRC wasn't much fun to setup either. See http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=101151

Comment: @GeorgNordal  ps: you can obtain preset keymap tables in `/lib/udev/rc_keymaps`. Copy the required ones to `/etc/rc_keymaps`. If you read some of the how-tos via Google, note that older how-tos still refer to LIRC, so ignore those, just read about the ir-keytable usage.

Comment: @GeorgNordal ps2: also see http://madaboutbrighton.net/articles/2015/remote-control-media-player-without-lirc-using-ir-keymap

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all assistance, but I have given up.
Have gone back to Ubuntu 16 and LIRC. 
My remote is working perfectly in KODI again.:)
Sorry, i just don't have the time to learn how to get it to work with Ubuntu 17.