# Cannot configure lirc on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: python, 17.10, lirc

I just installed `lirc` on my Ubuntu 17.10 computer and I can't choose IR device. Usually this was performed when installing `lirc`, however no dialog appeared when I installed it using

```
sudo apt install lirc
```

So, I tried to configure it manually with

```
lirc-setup
```

But this failed too, with a Python error saying it cannot find module `lirc`:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.6/site-packages/lirc-setup/mvc_control.py:13: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk         # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lirc-setup", line 16, in <module>
import mvc_control
  File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.6/site-packages/lirc-setup/mvc_control.py", line 16, in <module>
import choosers
  File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.6/site-packages/lirc-setup/choosers.py", line 11, in <module>
import mvc_model
  File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.6/site-packages/lirc-setup/mvc_model.py", line 14, in <module>
    from lirc.database import Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lirc'
```

I tried installing `python-pylirc`, but it didn't solve the problem.

**How can I run `lirc-setup`?**

Comment: You can't , see this link below https://askubuntu.com/questions/908810/ir-remote-ubuntu-17-04

Comment: There is an article here that shows how to make LIRC work in Ubuntu 18.04: https://twosortoftechguys.wordpress.com/2018/07/24/make-lirc-work-in-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 2):

The above did not work for me. Got an error doing the pip3 install that I could not resolve, presumably because I don't know  python that well.

I fixed the problem by downloading the latest build from SourceForge. The link is on lirc.org. You have to unpack the tar, run config, then make install.

Also, you may need to install the package lirc-compat-remotes which defines lots of remote controls, such as for mce.

Answer (score 1):

you can fix this error and get lirc-setup to run in ubuntu 17.10 or higher by opening a terminal and typing these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 install /usr/share/lirc/lirc-0.10.0.tar.gz
```

lirc-setup will now run, but you will get a pop up box telling you to add yourself to the usergroup 'lirc' . I had to first create the group with

```
sudo groupadd lirc
```

I then copied the 2 commands from the pop up box and got the lirc gui to run